# Renaming columns recursively in a nested structure in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to replace certain characters in all the columns of my DataFrame which has lot of nested Struct Types.

I tried to process the schema fields recursively and for some reason it is only renaming the fields at the top level even through it is reaching the leaf nodes.

I am trying replace the `:` char in the column name with `_`

Here is the scala code I have writte:

```
class UpdateSchema {
  
  val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(classOf[UpdateSchema])
  
  Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.OFF)
  
  Logger.getLogger("akka").setLevel(Level.OFF)
  
  val sparkSession = SparkLauncher.spark

  import sparkSession.implicits._   

  def updateSchema(filePath:String):Boolean ={
    logger.info(".updateSchema() : filePath ={}",filePath);
    logger.info(".updateSchema() : sparkSession ={}",sparkSession);
    if(sparkSession!=null){
      var xmlDF = sparkSession
                  .read
                  .format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
                  .option("rowTag","ns:fltdMessage")
                  .option("inferschema","true")
                  .option("attributePrefix","attr_")
                  .load(filePath)
                  .toDF()
      
      xmlDF.printSchema()
      val updatedDF = renameDataFrameColumns(xmlDF.toDF()) 
      updatedDF.printSchema()
    }
    else
      logger.info(".updateSchema(): Spark Session is NULL !!!");
    false;
  }


    def replaceSpecialChars(str:String):String ={
          val newColumn:String =  str.replaceAll(":", "_")
          //logger.info(".replaceSpecialChars() : Old Column Name =["+str+"] New Column Name =["+newColumn+"]")
          return newColumn
      }
      
      def renameColumn(df:DataFrame,colName:String,prefix:String):DataFrame ={
        val newColuName:String = replaceSpecialChars(colName)
        logger.info(".renameColumn(): prefix=["+prefix+"] colName=["+colName+"] New Column Name=["+newColuName+"]")
        if(prefix.equals("")){
          if(df.col(colName)!=null){
            return df.withColumnRenamed(colName, replaceSpecialChars(colName))
          }
          else{
            logger.error(".logSchema() : Column ["+prefix+"."+colName+"] Not found in DataFrame !! ")
            logger.info("Prefix ="+prefix+" Existing Columns =["+df.columns.mkString("),(")+"]")
            throw new Exception("Unable to find Column ["+prefix+"."+colName+"]")
          }
        }
        else{
          if(df.col(prefix+"."+colName)!=null){
            return df.withColumnRenamed(prefix+"."+colName, prefix+"."+replaceSpecialChars(colName))
          }
          else{
            logger.error(".logSchema() : Column ["+prefix+"."+colName+"] Not found in DataFrame !! ")
            logger.info("Prefix ="+prefix+" Existing Columns =["+df.columns.mkString("),(")+"]")
            throw new Exception("Unable to find Column ["+prefix+"."+colName+"]")
          }
        }
      }
      
      def getStructType(schema:StructType,fieldName:String):StructType = {
        schema.fields.foreach(field => {
              field.dataType match{
                case st:StructType => {
                  logger.info(".getStructType(): Current Field Name =["+field.name.toString()+"] Checking for =["+fieldName+"]")
                  if(field.name.toString().equals(fieldName)){
                    return field.dataType.asInstanceOf[StructType]
                  }
                  else{
                    getStructType(st,fieldName)
                  }
                }
                case _ =>{
                  logger.info(".getStructType(): Non Struct Type. Ignoring Filed=["+field.name.toString()+"]");
                }
              }
          })
          throw new Exception("Unable to find Struct Type for filed Name["+fieldName+"]")
      }
      
      def processSchema(df:DataFrame,schema:StructType,prefix:String):DataFrame ={
        var updatedDF:DataFrame =df
        schema.fields.foreach(field =>{
          field.dataType match {
            case st:StructType => {
                logger.info(".processSchema() : Struct Type =["+st+"]");
                logger.info(".processSchema() : Field Data Type =["+field.dataType+"]");
                logger.info(".processSchema() : Renaming the Struct Field =["+field.name.toString()+"] st=["+st.fieldNames.mkString(",")+"]") 
                updatedDF = renameColumn(updatedDF,field.name.toString(),prefix)
                logger.info(".processSchema() : Column List after Rename =["+updatedDF.columns.mkString(",")+"]")
               // updatedDF.schema.fields.foldLeft(z)(op)
                val renamedCol:String = replaceSpecialChars(field.name.toString())
                var fieldType:DataType = null;
                //if(prefix.equals(""))
                fieldType = schema.fields.find(f =>{ (f.name.toString().equals(field.name.toString()))}).get.dataType
                
                if(prefix.trim().equals("") 
                    //&& fieldType.isInstanceOf[StructType]
                    ){
                  updatedDF = processSchema(updatedDF,
                      getStructType(updatedDF.schema,renamedCol),
                      replaceSpecialChars(field.name.toString()))
                }
                else{
                  updatedDF = processSchema(updatedDF,
                      getStructType(updatedDF.schema,renamedCol),
                      prefix+"."+replaceSpecialChars(field.name.toString()))
                }
              }
            case _ => {
              updatedDF = renameColumn(updatedDF,field.name.toString(),prefix)
            }
          }
        })
        //updatedDF.printSchema()
        
        
        return updatedDF
      }
      
      def renameDataFrameColumns(df:DataFrame):DataFrame ={
        val schema = df.schema;
        return processSchema(df,schema,"")
      }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a recursive method that revise a DataFrame schema by renaming via `replaceAll` any columns whose name consists of a substring to be replaced:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

def renameAllColumns(schema: StructType, from: String, to: String): StructType = {
  def recurRename(schema: StructType, from: String, to:String): Seq[StructField] =
    schema.fields.map{
      case StructField(name, dtype: StructType, nullable, meta) =>
        StructField(name.replaceAll(from, to), StructType(recurRename(dtype, from, to)), nullable, meta)
      case StructField(name, dtype: ArrayType, nullable, meta) => dtype.elementType match {
          case struct: StructType => StructField(name.replaceAll(from, to), ArrayType(StructType(recurRename(struct, from, to)), true), nullable, meta)
          case other => StructField(name.replaceAll(from, to), other, nullable, meta)
        }
      case StructField(name, dtype, nullable, meta) =>
        StructField(name.replaceAll(from, to), dtype, nullable, meta)
    }

  StructType(recurRename(schema, from, to))
}
```

Testing the method on a sample DataFrame with a nested structure:

```
case class M(i: Int, `p:q`: String)
case class N(j: Int, m: M)

val df = Seq(
  (1, "a", Array(N(7, M(11, "x")), N(72, M(112, "x2")))),
  (2, "b", Array(N(8, M(21, "y")))),
  (3, "c", Array(N(9, M(31, "z"))))
).toDF("c1", "c2:0", "c3")

df.printSchema
// root
//  |-- c1: integer (nullable = false)
//  |-- c2:0: string (nullable = true)
//  |-- c3: array (nullable = true)
//  |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
//  |    |    |-- j: integer (nullable = false)
//  |    |    |-- m: struct (nullable = true)
//  |    |    |    |-- i: integer (nullable = false)
//  |    |    |    |-- p:q: string (nullable = true)

val newSchema = renameAllColumns(df.schema, ":", "_")

spark.createDataFrame(df.rdd, newSchema).printSchema
// root
//  |-- c1: integer (nullable = false)
//  |-- c2_0: string (nullable = true)
//  |-- c3: array (nullable = true)
//  |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
//  |    |    |-- j: integer (nullable = false)
//  |    |    |-- m: struct (nullable = true)
//  |    |    |    |-- i: integer (nullable = false)
//  |    |    |    |-- p_q: string (nullable = true)
```

---

Note that since method `replaceAll` supports `Regex` pattern, one can apply the method with more versatile replacement condition.  For example, here's how to trim off column name starting from the ':' character:

```
val newSchema = renameAllColumns(df.schema, """:.*""", "")

spark.createDataFrame(df.rdd, newSchema).printSchema
// root
//  |-- c1: integer (nullable = false)
//  |-- c2: string (nullable = true)
//  |-- c3: array (nullable = true)
//  |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
//  |    |    |-- j: integer (nullable = false)
//  |    |    |-- m: struct (nullable = true)
//  |    |    |    |-- i: integer (nullable = false)
//  |    |    |    |-- p: string (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't easily rename a single nested field using `withFieldRenamed` liked you are attempting to do.  The only way I know of to rename nested fields is to do a cast on the field provided a type with the same structure and data types but new field names.  This has to be done on the top level field, so you need to do all the fields in one go.  Here is an example:

Create some input data

```
case class InnerRecord(column1: String, column2: Int)
case class Record(field: InnerRecord)

val df = Seq(
    Record(InnerRecord("a", 1)),
    Record(InnerRecord("b", 2))
).toDF

df.printSchema
```

Input data looks like this:

```
root
 |-- field: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- column1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- column2: integer (nullable = false)
```

This is an example using withColumnRenamed.  You'll notice in the output it doesn't actually do anything!

```
val updated = df.withColumnRenamed("field.column1", "field.newname")
updated.printSchema

root
 |-- field: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- column1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- column2: integer (nullable = false)
```

Here is how you can do it instead with casting.  The function will recursively recreate the nested field type while updating the name.  In my case I just replaced "column" with "col_".  I also only ran it on one field, but you could easily loop across all your fields in schema.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

def rename(dataType: DataType): DataType = dataType match {
    case StructType(fields) => 
        StructType(fields.map { 
            case StructField(name, dtype, nullable, meta) => 
                val newName = name.replace("column", "col_")
                StructField(newName, rename(dtype), nullable, meta)
        })

    case _ => dataType
}


val fDataType = df.schema.filter(_.name == "field").head.dataType
val updated = df.withColumn("field", $"field".cast(rename(fDataType)))
updated.printSchema
```

Which prints:

```
root
 |-- field: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- col_1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- col_2: integer (nullable = false)
```

Comment: Thanks for the inputs Ryan.Really appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

I had some issues with the answer from @Leo C, so I've used a slight variation instead. It also takes in any mapping function `f` to rename.

```
def renameAllColumns(schema: StructType, f: String => String): StructType = {
  def recurRename(schema: StructType, f: String => String): Seq[StructField] =
    schema.fields.map{
      case StructField(name, dtype: StructType, nullable, meta) =>
        StructField(f(name), StructType(recurRename(dtype, f)), nullable, meta)
      case StructField(name, dtype: ArrayType, nullable, meta) => dtype.elementType match {
          case struct: StructType => StructField(f(name), ArrayType(StructType(recurRename(struct, f)), true), nullable, meta)
          case other => StructField(f(name), ArrayType(other), nullable, meta)
        }
      case StructField(name, dtype, nullable, meta) =>
        StructField(f(name), dtype, nullable, meta)
    }

  StructType(recurRename(schema, f))
}
```