# How to change the datatype of a column in StructField of a StructType?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to change the datatype of a column present in a dataframe I that I am reading from an RDBMS database.
To do that, I got the schema of the dataframe in the below way:

```
val dataSchema = dataDF.schema
```

To see the schema of the dataframe, I used the below statement:

```
println(dataSchema.schema)

Output: StructType(StructField(je_header_id,LongType,true), StructField(je_line_num,LongType,true), StructField(last_update_date,TimestampType,true), StructField(last_updated_by,DecimalType(15,0),true), StructField(creation_date,TimestampType,true), StructField(created_by,DecimalType(15,0),true), StructField(created_by_name,StringType,true), StructField(entered_dr,DecimalType(38,30),true), StructField(entered_cr,DecimalType(38,30),true))
```

My requirement is find the DecimalType and change it to DoubleType from the above schema.
I can get the column name and the datatypes using: dataSchema.dtype but it gives me the datatypes in the format of `((columnName1, column datatype),(columnName2, column datatype)....(columnNameN, column datatype))`

I am trying to find a way to parse the StructType and change the schema in dataSchema in vain.

Could anyone let me know if there is a way to parse the StructType so that I can change the datatype to my requirement and get in the below format

```
StructType(StructField(je_header_id,LongType,true), StructField(je_line_num,LongType,true), StructField(last_update_date,TimestampType,true), StructField(last_updated_by,DoubleType,true), StructField(creation_date,TimestampType,true), StructField(created_by,DoubleType,true), StructField(created_by_name,StringType,true), StructField(entered_dr,DoubleType,true), StructField(entered_cr,DoubleType,true))
```

Comment: Map over the schema and return column name or column name with cast, then you can use it as select expression to enforce the new schema

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To modify a DataFrame Schema specific to a given data type, you can pattern-match against [StructField](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField)'s `dataType`, as shown below:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val df = Seq(
  (1L, BigDecimal(12.34), "a", BigDecimal(10.001)),
  (2L, BigDecimal(56.78), "b", BigDecimal(20.002))
).toDF("c1", "c2", "c3", "c4")

val newSchema = df.schema.fields.map{
  case StructField(name, _: DecimalType, nullable, _)
    => StructField(name, DoubleType, nullable)
  case field => field
}
// newSchema: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField] = Array(
//   StructField(c1,LongType,false), StructField(c2,DoubleType,true),
//   StructField(c3,StringType,true), StructField(c4,DoubleType,true)
// )
```

However, assuming your end-goal is to transform the dataset with the column type change, it would be easier to just traverse the columns for the targeted data type to iteratively `cast` them, like below:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df2 = df.dtypes.
  collect{ case (dn, dt) if dt.startsWith("DecimalType") => dn }.
  foldLeft(df)((accDF, c) => accDF.withColumn(c, col(c).cast("Double")))

df2.printSchema
// root
//  |-- c1: long (nullable = false)
//  |-- c2: double (nullable = true)
//  |-- c3: string (nullable = true)
//  |-- c4: double (nullable = true)
```

[UPDATE]

Per additional requirement from comments, if you want to change schema only for `DecimalType` with positive scale, just apply a Regex pattern-match as the `guard` condition in method `collect`:

```
val pattern = """DecimalType\(\d+,(\d+)\)""".r

val df2 = df.dtypes.
  collect{ case (dn, dt) if pattern.findFirstMatchIn(dt).map(_.group(1)).getOrElse("0") != "0" => dn }.
  foldLeft(df)((accDF, c) => accDF.withColumn(c, col(c).cast("Double")))
```

Comment: how do you change it if the column is inside a ````struct````

Comment: @stack0114106, obviously the existing solution is for transforming only the top-level columns for the targeted data type, and that should be adequate for a typical RDBMS table (which is OP's data source).  To handle an arbitrarily nested column structure, I would consider using a
recursive traversal similar to this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51334193/6316508).

Comment: Great!.. thank you so much for the recursive solution.

Comment: @Metadata, since `foldLeft` keeps order of traversed elements and `withColumn(c, col(c)...)` reuses the same name for the new column, the order of columns should remain the same.  In any case, if for whatever reason order of columns is changed, you can always enforce it with an explicit `select` (e.g. `df2.select(df.columns.map(col): _*)`).

Comment: @LeoC, One last doubt. In the schema given, there are some elements like: DecimalType(15,0) these are essentially INTEGER datatypes from the RDBMS table as there is no precision for them. How do I ignore these types of decimals and only convert the ones that have precision like: DECIMAL(38,30)

Comment: @LeoC could you please give a try to my question 54445014

Comment: @Metadata, please see expanded answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way:

```
data.show(false)
data.printSchema

+----+------------------------+----+----------------------+
|col1|col2                    |col3|col4                  |
+----+------------------------+----+----------------------+
|1   |0.003200000000000000    |a   |23.320000000000000000 |
|2   |78787.990030000000000000|c   |343.320000000000000000|
+----+------------------------+----+----------------------+

root
 |-- col1: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- col2: decimal(38,18) (nullable = true)
 |-- col3: string (nullable = true)
 |-- col4: decimal(38,18) (nullable = true)
```

Create a schema that you want:
Exampe:

```
val newSchema = StructType(
  Seq(
    StructField("col1", StringType, true),
    StructField("col2", DoubleType, true),
    StructField("col3", StringType, true),
    StructField("col4", DoubleType, true)
  )
)
```

Cast the columns to the required datatype.

```
val newDF = data.selectExpr(newSchema.map(
   col => s"CAST ( ${col.name} As ${col.dataType.sql}) ${col.name}"
  ): _*)

newDF.printSchema

root
 |-- col1: string (nullable = false)
 |-- col2: double (nullable = true)
 |-- col3: string (nullable = true)
 |-- col4: double (nullable = true) 

newDF.show(false)
+----+-----------+----+------+
|col1|col2       |col3|col4  |
+----+-----------+----+------+
|1   |0.0032     |a   |23.32 |
|2   |78787.99003|c   |343.32|
+----+-----------+----+------+
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it resulted in: 
used by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Decimal precision 39 exceeds max precision 38
Could you let me know what can be done here ?

Comment: There is a known issue - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-20427

Answer (score 1):

The accepted solution works great, but its very costly because of huge cost of withColumn, and analyzer has to analyze whole DF for each withColumn, and with a large number of columns it is very costly. I would rather suggest doing this -

```
val transformedColumns = inputDataDF.dtypes
      .collect {
        case (dn, dt)
            if (dt.startsWith("DecimalType")) =>
          (dn, DoubleType)
      }

    val transformedDF = inputDataDF.select(transformedColumns.map { fieldType =>
      inputDataDF(fieldType._1).cast(fieldType._2)
    }: _*)
```

For a very small dataset it took 1+ minute with withColumn approach for me in my machine and 100 ms with approach with select.

you can read more about cost of withColumn here - https://medium.com/@manuzhang/the-hidden-cost-of-spark-withcolumn-8ffea517c015